# Reuse umbraco grid with custom viewmodel

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco7

I'm new to the new umbraco grid functionality and I have a question about it.

I have a page with an article where I use the grid functionality to show some image and text besides that image. This is working fine.

In the properties of that page I have put a checkbox for saying that the article is for sale or not, when checked the product should automatically appear on a for sale page.

I can get the product that is for sale on that page, but now I also want to show the image and text on that page. I've created a List with a custom viewmodel to hold the content for every product that is for sale. The problem is with providing the JObject to the GetGridHtml function. This function wants a string and I'm providing the property which results in an error.

What is the best way to get the content for the grid to show on that separate page?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
     var home = CurrentPage.Site();

     List<ForSaleItemsViewModel> forSaleItemsVM = new List<ForSaleItemsViewModel>();

     if(home.Children.Any())
     {        
         foreach(var childPage in home.Children)
         {
             if(childPage.Children.Any())
             {
                 foreach(var child in childPage.Children)
                 {
                     if(child.HasProperty("ForSale") && child.ForSale)
                     {
                           forSaleItemsVM.Add(new ForSaleItemsViewModel
                                            {
                                                ID = 1,
                                                Content = child.Content,
                                                Sold = child.Sold
                                            });
                     }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}

<div class="container">
    @foreach(var item in forSaleItemsVM)
    {
        if (item.Sold)
        {
            <span>SOLD!</span>
        }
        CurrentPage.GetGridHtml(item.Content.ToString(), "bootstrap3");
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Umbraco forum it is not possible to do this. I got this answer:

> If you see the documentation for best pratices for the grid layout
>   https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Using-Umbraco/Backoffice-Overview/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors-v7/Grid-Layout-Best-Practices
>   there is a chapter about the limitations for the grid layout
>   https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Using-Umbraco/Backoffice-Overview/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors-v7/Grid-Layout-Best-Practices#Limitations.
>   And of the limitions of using the grid layout is that it´s not for
>   reused content.
>
> It says - There is no managed api to drill into the grid content and
>   target specific cell content - so a grid layout is not a recommended
>   storage of reusable content - it simply wasn't designed for this
>   scenario. If you wish to reuse content in multiple pages, it is still
>   recommended that you store these pieces of content as seperate content
>   nodes, so they can be stored, cached and queried as usual.